# Error in class MyApp - caused by: Cannot read property 'setRoot' of undefined

Tags: ionic2

I just created an `ActivitiesPage` using `ionic g page activities`. Following is the default page generated by the CLI.

**`ActivitiesPage` (activities.ts)**

```
// imports..

@Component({
  selector: 'page-activities',
  templateUrl: 'activities.html'
})
export class ActivitiesPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams){}
}
```

I've setup a side menu from where user can select `Activities` from a list of pages.

**`Class MyApp` (app.component.ts)**

```
import { ActivitiesPage } from '../pages/activities/activities';
// other imports

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
})
export class MyApp
{
  @ViewChild(NavController) navCtrl: NavController;
  rootPage = LoginPage; // TabsPage for bottom nav tabs
  activitiesPage: any = ActivitiesPage;

  constructor(public platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page: any)
  {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(page);
  }

}
```

**`App Template` (app.html)**

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>RnB MENU</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>

      <button ion-item (click)="openPage(HomePage)">
        <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;
         Home
      </button>

      <button ion-item (click)="openPage(MessagesPage)">
        <ion-icon name="chatboxes"></ion-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Messages
      </button>

      <button ion-item (click)="openPage(ActivitiesPage)">
        <ion-icon name="analytics"></ion-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Activities
      </button>

     </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav id="nav" #content [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to open `ActivitiesPage` via the menu.

> Error in ./MyApp class MyApp - caused by: Cannot read property 'setRoot' of undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error seems to be emerging from the fact that `navCtrl` class member in class **MyApp** is not initialized.

Try to change the definiion of `navCtrl` in class **MyApp** as follows:

```
@ViewChild('content') navCtrl: NavController;
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it!